# (c++14) operator<< overloading not working as expected from vector of smart pointers

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++14, smart-pointers

I am doing something wrong here, but i am not sure what. I expect the output of the program to be "tacos!", but I am getting a memory location instead.

I am trying to use C++14 features. In this program I am attempting to use smart pointers and overload the << operator.

A tacoCalendar object holds a vector smart pointers for tacoTuesdays objects, of which one is created on tacoCalendar's initialization. The `cout << month.my_tacoTuesdays.at(0).get();` line should get send the pointee of the first smart pointer of the `tacoTuesdays` vector in `month` to the friend function `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const tacoTuesdays& tt);` resulting in "tacos!" being returned and sent to `std::cout`.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class tacoTuesdays {
public:
    tacoTuesdays(int i) {
        _i = i;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const tacoTuesdays& tt);
private:
    int _i;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const tacoTuesdays& tt) {
    std::string str_out = "tacos!";
    os << str_out;
    return os;
}

typedef std::shared_ptr< tacoTuesdays > smart_tacoTuesdays_t;

class tacoCalendar {
public:
    std::vector<smart_tacoTuesdays_t> my_tacoTuesdays;
    tacoCalendar(int i) {
        smart_tacoTuesdays_t tt(new tacoTuesdays(i));
        my_tacoTuesdays.push_back(tt);
    }
    ~tacoCalendar() {
    }
private:
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    using namespace std;
    tacoCalendar month(2);
    cout << *month.my_tacoTuesdays.at(0).get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr<T>::get()` returns a `T*`, but your `operator<<` overload (correctly) takes a reference rather than a pointer.

Change

```
cout << month.my_tacoTuesdays.at(0).get();
```

to

```
cout << *month.my_tacoTuesdays.at(0);
```

Or if any `shared_ptr` instance can be null,

```
if (auto* p = month.my_tacoTuesdays.at(0).get()) {
    cout << *p;
}
```

Comment: You won't need the `.get()` either

Comment: What is "auto* p =" doing as a condition here?

Comment: @USERID_UNK : It's declaring and initializing a `tacoTuesdays*` (via `auto` for brevity) and only entering the `if` if the pointer is non-null.

Comment: @ildjarn , @povman, is there any way to get `cout << month.my_tacoTuesdays.at(0).get();` to work without including the dereferencing operator in `main()`?

Comment: @USERID_UNK : Sure, create another `operator<<` overload – `std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream&, const tacoTuesdays*)` – and do the dereferencing in there instead. (And don't forget the null check.)

Answer (score 3):

Pay attention to the type of `cout`:

```
cout << month.my_tacoTuesdays.at(0).get();
```

It is printing the `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<tacoTuesdays>>::at(0).get(0)`, which is a pointer `tacoTuesdays*`, so `cout` print the raw pointer address for you.

To get what you want, you should pass `tacoTuesdays`'s `const reference`, like this:

```
cout << *month.my_tacoTuesdays.at(0);
```